# How does GLOBIGNORE work?

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, wildcards

According to bash's manual page:

```
   GLOBIGNORE
          A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames
          to be ignored by pathname expansion.  If a filename matched by a
          pathname  expansion  pattern also matches one of the patterns in
          GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.
```

However in practice...

```
$ bash --noprofile --norc
bash-4.2$ touch .bar
bash-4.2$ echo .*
. .. .bar
bash-4.2$ GLOBIGNORE=.
bash-4.2$ echo .*
.bar
```

Why is `..` removed from the list of matches? As far as I know, the pattern
`.` does NOT match `..`, does it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Scroll down](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)…

> The filenames `.` and `..` are always ignored when `GLOBIGNORE` is set and not null.

Most of the time, it is not desirable to include `.` and `..` as wildcard matches, since they don't represent files inside the directory — they're hacks to make directory navigation work. In fact, the origin of dot files is [a bug in an early version of the `ls` command](https://web.archive.org/web/20181206210551/https://plus.google.com/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp). The author meant to exclude `.` and `..` from the listing but accidentally excluded all files that begin with `.`. Thus dot files became hidden from `ls`. Shells followed suit by hiding dot files like `ls`. However the way this was done was again a hack: files beginning with `.` are only excluded if the dot isn't matched explicitly in the pattern. So the pattern `.*` includes `.` and `..`.

To preserve compatibility with existing scripts, modern shells still include `.` and `..` (except zsh, which on this issue like many others has a saner but not backward compatible behavior). However, if you set `GLOBIGNORE`, you are using a bash-specific feature, which shows that you aren't interested in backward compatibility. So pattern matching changes to exclude `.` and `..` from all pattern matches.

Setting `GLOBIGNORE=.` excludes a file that is excluded automatically anyway whenever `GLOBIGNORE` is set, so it is equivalent to `shopt -s dotglob` except that `.` and `..` are furthermore excluded from all patterns.

Comment: Actually, I just realised setting `GLOBIGNORE` only ignore `.` and `..` in slash-less patterns and GLOBIGNORE filters file paths not file names. `GLOBIGNORE=.; echo .*` will not include `.` nor `..`, but `GLOBIGNORE=.; echo ./.*` (or `echo /bin/.*`) will! To ignore `.` and `..` from all globs, it looks like you need `shopt -s extglob` and `GLOBIGNORE='?(*/)@(.|..)'`.

Comment: Actually, no, `GLOBIGNORE='?(*/)@(.|..)'` would fail to exclude `.` and `..` in `.*/foo`. `GLOBIGNORE='?(*/)@(.|..)?(/*)'` would break globs like `./*`...

Answer (score 3):

From the section entitled "Pathname Expansion" in `man bash`:

> The  file names ''.''  and ''..''  are always ignored when GLOBIGNORE
>   is set and not null.